# Merge a remote branch into another local branch

Tags: git, github

This might be a duplicate question, but I couldn't figure out how can I go about it. I'm trying to merge a remote branch say `remoteBranch` which is not a master branch to my local branch `localBranch`.

One of my developer added a new branch for an api end point on remote branch `remoteBranch`. As a frontend developer, I need to fetch that branch and merge it with my local development branch `localBranch` to make use of that api end point. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use `git merge remoteBranch` while `localBranch` is checked out?

Comment: This question shows very little research effort of a well-documented feature.

Comment: Things are confusing if we don't have enough experience in such things even if there are well documented things. You'll get confused with close enough features. Thats why I asked for help. Sorry if it didn't meet your expectations. I'm just learning stuffs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply merge it.

```
git fetch
git checkout localBranch
git merge remoteBranch
```

Comment: `error: pathspec 'remoteBranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: When I try to merge, I get this message: `not something we can merge`

Comment: It should work without the origin too. Try `git merge remoteBranch`

Comment: @user1012181 Obviously you have to use your *real* branch names, not literally `remoteBranch`...

Comment: @mkrieger1 used the real branch name :)

Comment: @user1012181 Then most likely the other user haven't pushed that branch yet.

Comment: @user1012181 Your remote might be called `origin` in which case it would be something like `origin/myBranch`.

Answer (score 14):

According to the documentation of [`git-merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) you can merge any other branch with your local branch.

Your current branch has to be your `localBranch`. To merge the remote branch simply type:

```
git merge remoteName/remoteBranch
```

In this case I assumed the name of your remote that contains the branch you need to be called `remoteName`. It may be called differently like `origin` or `upstream`. You need to make sure that your local reference to the remove branch is up to date. So perform a [`fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) command before doing the merge like so:

```
git fetch remoteName
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks for the most to-the-point answer! :)

Answer (score 6):

To merge remoteBranch into localBranch

```
git fetch
git merge localBranch remoteName/remoteBranch
```

where remoteName is probably "origin", you can find that by `git remote -v`

However, sometimes you may want to rebase (re-writing history to keep sequence of commits "clean") instead of merge (which also adds a merge commit)

[image: Merge vs. Rebase]

You can rebase a remoteBranch into a localBranch using:

```
git fetch
git checkout localBranch
git rebase remoteName/remoteBranch
```

ref: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

Answer (score 2):

Can use the following too, to achieve same:

```
git pull origin origin-branch-name:local-branch-name
```

above will merge the origin branch with local branch, keeping active intact

```
git pull another-local-branch:another2-local-branch
```

it should (not tested) merge the two different branches while keeping active intact

Answer (score 0):

These answers are confusing because I look here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch
and the command is

```
git fetch <remote> <branch>
```

to fetch a specific branch from remote to local

Then I'm guessing, I actually am new to git, that I can `git checkout branchIwantToMergeInto` and then do `git merge <branch>` where there is now a local copy of `<branch>` after the original command.

So say I'm working on branch `hotfix` locally and I have to update this branch with changes made to the remote `staging` branch.
I would do the following sequence of commands.

```
git fetch <remote> staging
git checkout hotfix
git merge staging
```

but before `git checkout hotfix` I would ensure there are no untracked changes (again, I"m a git novice so unfamiliar with advanced commands like rebase, etc) by doing `git add .`, `git commit -m "my commit message"` to any relevant branches that could cause a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

In latest git:

```
git fetch origin remoteBranchName
git checkout localBranchName
git merge origin/remoteBranchName
```